# sed command is not working to remove the special character ( Copyright and trademark symbols )

Tags: sed, special-characters

I am trying to use sed command to delete the copyright characters.But it is not working. Below is the command which am using.

```
sed 's/; © E/; (c)/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

but when am using `vi` editor to open the file it is showing `\251`.

Could you please help me out.

Comment: This could be a matter of encoding. Which character set is the input file saved in? Try the `encguess` command if that's available on your system. Or provide an example for download.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone.

I got the solution as in perl :

```
perl -lape 's/[^[:print:]]*//g'
```

Comment: Note that this command will also remove all non-ASCII characters from the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nasty trick to do the job using hex codes.
For example in default UTF-8 ascii you can print `'` with `\x27` which is the hex code of single quotes.

```
echo -e "\x27hello\x27"
'hello'
```

The copyright symbol is not part of default ascii table but belongs on the extended ascii codes. You can also print extended ascii as a combination of hex codes

(as advised by http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm)

```
echo -e '\xc2\xa9'
©
```

Similarilly , you can use those hex codes in sed

```
a="hello ©"
sed 's/\xc2\xa9/??/' <<<"$a"  ##replacing copyright symbol with two questionmarks
hello ??
```

If \xc2\xa9 which stands for copyright symbol are not working, you can try \xe2\x92\xb8 which is the "CIRCLED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C".

Also try `\o251` (use a lowercase letter 'o', not a zero).